# C++ and zlib, help deflating a string

Tags: c++, string, zlib, deflate, inflate

I've been trying to deflate and inflate a string, and this works:

```
char text[600] = "Testing deflating and inflating";
char out[600];
uLong ucompSize = strlen(text) + 1; 
uLong compSize = compressBound(ucompSize);
// Deflate
compress((Bytef *)out, &compSize, (Bytef *)text, ucompSize);
```

But my problem is that the needed space for the out (and the string itself) can vary a lot, I tried using std::string 's but it doesn't work, I get the following error:

```
_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(pUserData)
```

My current code with std::string is this one

```
char text[600] = "Testing deflating and inflating";
std::string out;
uLong ucompSize = strlen(text) + 1; 
uLong compSize = compressBound(ucompSize);
// Deflate
compress((Bytef *)out.data(), &compSize, (Bytef *)text, ucompSize);
```

I've been searching in Google but I can't find a solution, I just need to inflate and deflate big strings. I'm not good in C++ (I always work with Ruby, where I can do this just with Zlib::Deflate.deflate(@string))

Can anyone help/teach me? Thanks you

Comment: You need dynamic memory allocation. The obvious way to proceed is to [learn some C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 4):

According to [zlib manual](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html) the function `compress`:

> Compresses the source buffer into the destination buffer. `sourceLen` is
>   the byte length of the source buffer. Upon entry, `destLen` is the total
>   size of the destination buffer, which must be at least the value
>   returned by `compressBound(sourceLen)`. Upon exit, destLen is the actual
>   size of the compressed buffer.

C++ std::string cannot be used for such buffer. The member function `std::string::data()` returns read-only string buffer that should not be changed by external functions.

In C++11 it is possible to use `std::vector::data()` for such buffer after allocating enough size for vector of bytes: `std::vector<char> out(compressBound(sourceLen));`

Here for C style functions it also might be simpler to allocate that buffer using `malloc`. However, in that case the buffer should be manually freed (in case of C++ vector the buffer memory is deallocated when the vector instance is destroyed).

So, the C++11 code may look like:

```
{
    char text[600] = "Testing deflating and inflating";
    uLong ucompSize = strlen(text) + 1;
    uLong compSize = compressBound(ucompSize);
    std::vector<char> dest(compSize); // allocate enough size for output buffer
    // Deflate
    int error = compress((Bytef *)dest.data(), &compSize, (Bytef *)text, ucompSize);
    // here if error code is Z_OK the variable compSize contains size of
    // compressed data that is usually smaller than initial buffer size.
    // vector size may be adjusted to actual size of compressed data
    dest.resize(compSize);

    // do something with compressed data
    // ...
}
// here the vector 'dest' is out of block scope;
// it is automatically destroed and the buffer is not valid anymore.
```